# Problem with a wavefunction in Quantum Mechanics (math) (Book solution possibly wrong?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Well there is a problem in my book which lists this problem:

> Calculate the probability that a particle will be found at $0.49L$ and $0.51L$ in a box of length $L$ when it has (a) $n = 1$. Take the wave function to be constant in this range.

The answer in the solutions manual for this specific problem is given as:

[image: Solution]

However when I workout the equation myself I get this:

[image: What I got]

So i don't understand why the solutions book says that:
$$\frac{2}{L}\int \sin^2 \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \approx \frac{2 \Delta x}{L} \sin^2 \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) $$

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Hi, any feedback on my answer would be nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have missed a factor $2$ in your calculation. [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1o4m4rat8e) confirms that
$$
\frac2L \int_{.49L}^{.51L} \sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}L\right) dx= 0.399,
$$
which is close to the approximation given in your solution book:
$$
\frac{2 \Delta x}{L} \sin^2 \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)=\frac{2 \cdot 0.02L}{L} \sin^2 \left(\frac{.5L \pi}{L} \right)=0.04\sin^2\left(\frac\pi 2\right)=0.04
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry about delay in feedback. You're right the book does give this approximation, but why use this when you can use the method I used?? That doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Because the function is very close to constant over that range it can be pulled outside the integral.  It gives a very good approximation to the correct answer without the need to do anything but simple multiplication